# MySqlQuery using Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, echo

I need some help with this code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$Servico=implode(" ", $_POST['service']);

$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");  //I hid the info here

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Falhou a conexão ao MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$to = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Email FROM utilizadores WHERE Nome LIKE '%$Servico%'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($to);
$row['Email'];
foreach ($row as $destino)
    {
        echo $destino;
    }

?>
```

The array is created in other code, by selecting one or more users that exists in the database. Then it creates the array with the users selected.

When my array have only a name, it retrieves the email correctly, but when i have more than one, it gives me:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/a5301436/public_html/criartarefa.php on line 49
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `$Row` only contains one element, why do you need a loop?

Comment: That error will happen if the query doesn't find any matching rows. `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false` instead of an array.

Comment: I'm using the Krish R's code. I get the email if the array contains one user, but in case of two or more, shows me blank page.

Comment: That's because your `LIKE` expression doesn't match any of them. `LIKE '%foo bar baz%'` will only match something that contains exactly `foo bar baz` in it, it doesn't match any of them by themselves.

Comment: How can i do it then? In some cases, i have one user, but others can be ten and i need to retrieve the 1 or 10 emails.

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches, or does it have to be a substring matched with `LIKE`? If it's exact, you should use `IN`.

Comment: Please show sample data and the expected results.

Comment: @Barmar, The $Servico contains the name of the users separated by spaces, per example "Luis Sara Tiago" without the quotation marks. What im trying to do is to use those names separately, checking one by one in my database, on the users table. I can only pick users that already exists so the names have mandatorily an email associated. I need to retrieve the email of each user and storage them in $destino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it using `IN`.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");  //I hid the info here

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Falhou a conexão ao MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Servico=implode(", ", array_map(function($s) use ($con) {
    return "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $s) . "'";
    }, $_POST['service']));

$to = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Email FROM utilizadores WHERE Nome IN ($Servico)");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($to)){ 
    echo $row['Email'];
}
```

Comment: Is it missing some code? It gives me error on }, $_POST['service']);

Comment: Sorry, was missing a parenthesis. Fixed now.

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home/a5301436/public_html/criartarefa.php on line 44"

Comment: Are you using PHP older than 5.3? That's when anonymous functions were added.

Comment: Im using a temporarily server with PHP version 5.2. I'll transfer for another with 5.3. I'll let you know asap.

Comment: it worked! :) Now, i have the two emails "merged", i need to add a space or better a ";" so i can use one or more emails automatically when i send an notification by email, but now i dont have any variable that saves the emails.

Comment: Ok. I managed to save the emails on a variable formatted with ";" between emails but now, i realized that i dont want the emails to be echoed. I forgot about that... xD